# How to show pictures held by a p:dataTable in PDF, when the p:dataTable is exported as a PDF by a p:dataExporter?

Tags: image, jsf, pdf, primefaces, datatable

I want to show a picture in top of my `<p:dataTable>` in PrimeFaces. It works in XHTML but not working, when I export it as a PDF format. Is there anyway to show pictures and CSS styles in PDF export?

This is my XHTML page.

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="mydata" value="#{UserData.employees}" var="employee"  >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/icon/mellatlogo.png" style="height: 100px"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{employee.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">city</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{employee.city}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{employee.date}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:panel header="Export All Data">

        <h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/icon/pdf.jpg" />
            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="mydata" fileName="mypdf" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Does it mean that you want to export pictures and any textual information  along with all styles held by a `<p:dataTable>` as a PDF?

Comment: yes, I want it to looks like my xhtml, but its just showing a simpe table without any css style or my header picture.

Comment: You may [customize](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/customizedDocuments.xhtml) it using `<p:dataExporter postProcessor="#{bean.postProcessAction}"  type="..." target="..." fileName="..." .../>` and/or `<p:dataExporter preProcessor="#{bean.preProcessAction}"  type="..." target="..." fileName="..." .../>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add logo to PDF 
you have to use preProcessor attr in commandeButton

```
<h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/icon/pdf.jpg" />
            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="mydata" fileName="mypdf" preProcessor="#{yourBean.yourPreProcFunction}" />
        </h:commandLink>
```

Your preProcess function sould like,

```
        public void yourPreProcFunction(Object document) throws IOException, BadElementException, DocumentException{
    Document pdf = (Document) document;
ServletContext servletContext = (ServeletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
String logo = serveletContext.getRealPath("")+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"mellatlogo.png";
pdf.add(Image.getInstance(logo));

    }
```